# docker volumes in /var/www/html

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I would like to add a host computer directory into my docker container and replace the contents of the /var/www/html directory.

Then I presume when I make edits to my code and refresh the browser I can see the results of changes to the website.

Right?

This is my command

```
docker run --name simplesite --link joomla_db:mysql -d -p 8080:80  -v '/C/Users/Matt/Documents/website:/var/www/html' httpd
```

The inspect says this

```
> "Mounts": [
>             {
>                 "Type": "bind",
>                 "Source": "/C/Users/Matt/Documents/website",
>                 "Destination": "/var/www/html",
>                 "Mode": "",
>                 "RW": true,
>                 "Propagation": "rprivate"
>             }
>         ],
```

But I just don't see anything update.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I reordered the command sequence and it worked ...

```
docker run --name=simplesite -d -v /c/Users/matt/documents/docker/website:/var/www/html -p 8080:80  --link joomla_db:mysql joomla
```

Answer (score 1):

When start the container use

```
-v
```

option to add a host computer directory into my docker container

```
docker run --name container_name -v /host/computer:/var/www/html image_name
```

once you edit the code. then restart the container for effecting new code.

Comment: This is my command 
docker run --name simplesite --link joomla_db:mysql -d -p 8080:80  -v '/C/Users/Matt/Documents/website:/var/www/html' httpd
The inspect says this
 "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/C/Users/Matt/Documents/website",
                "Destination": "/var/www/html",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],

But I just don't see anything update.

Comment: try to create a new file in `/C/Users/Matt/Documents/website` then restart the container, and then access to container to see any new file?

Comment: @MatKay How are you checking whether something is updated or not?

Comment: I presume once the host is mounted i add or edit files to the host directory and refresh the browser?

Comment: the files will be effecting once restart the container @MatKay

Answer (score 1):

To mount directory from host machine into Docker you can use the `-v` or `--mount` flag

more information can be found here https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#choose-the--v-or-mount-flag

Example docker run command with mounts would look like:

```
docker run -v /var/www/html:/var/www/html image:tag
```

above command will mount `/var/www/html` from host computer into `/var/www/html` inside the container